# Moran’s I (spatial autocorrelation) in QGIS or SAGA?

Tags: qgis, saga, plugins, autocorrelation, moran-index

Is there a way (plugin/processing tool) to calculate Moran’s I as a measure of spatial auto correlation of a point pattern in QGIS or SAGA?

Comment: On what type of data? Polygons, points, raster? The more details you provide the better the advice you receive. Please read our FAQ on the intent of the site and how to ask a good question.

Comment: Points! Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, have a look at the following [plug-in](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/HotspotAnalysis/) . In case this does not fulfill your requirements, I recommend you [Crimestat IV](https://nij.ojp.gov/topics/articles/crimestat-spatial-statistics-program-analysis-crime-incident-locations). Their user guide provides an indepth spatial statistics analysis of data, including Moran's I. By the way, the data doesnt need to be crimedata.

Comment: Does this plugin actually return the Moran's-I? I see that it returns the local statistic but does not indicate that the global is part of the plug-in. Glad to see that Ned Levine is keeping CrimeStat up to date.

Comment: I can confirm that it includes Gi* local statistics, Moran's I and Local Moran Bivariate - I use this plugin all the time but you have to install dependencies

Comment: I cannot for the life of me get this plugin to work, chasing one error from the next, trying various versions. Do you know if it is, still being supported? If not, is there other ways to do this in 2021 in QGIS?

Comment: Try the Crimestat IV software instead!